# Compiling Multi2Sim with g++ compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, simulation

I am a newbee in Multi2Sim.
I saw that the whole project is based on pure C.
I wanted to add some files with C++ library functions. Whenever, I want to make Multi2Sim with these C++ files, I get errors.

I tried using CXX=g++ option in configure statement hoping that multi2sim will compiled using g++. But I got the same fatal error saying "iostream: no such file found".

It seems multi2sim is always compiled with C compiler gcc and NOT g++.

Is there any way I can force Multi2Sim to be compiled using g++ compiler?

Comment: Compiling C code as C++ code is a leading cause of psychosis.

Comment: I am integrating another project with M2S which is built using C++. I have to use g++ to compile them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a clean checkout and change the line:

```
AC_PROG_CC([gcc])
```

in configure.ac before doing anything else.

But I ain't saying it's gonna be fun. It's a pretty huge project to go messing around like that in.

Maybe doing without C++ for a while would make a nice change.

Update: I tried this and for reasons I don't uderstand, it didn't work. But just before `make` I run:

```
sed -i 's/gcc/g++/g' Makefile
```

and that seems to have some effect.

But I notice that there are C++ sources in that project anyway, so there's no need to screw around like this. Just call your file something.cc and add it to a Makefile.am, then re-run the whole autotools bootstrap thing.

Comment: I could not find any line AC_PROG_CC([gcc]). In the configure file I can see AC_PROG_CC and AC_PROG_CXX only.

Comment: I checked the downloaded one. That does not include that setting. Sorry for that.

Comment: This requires an updated gcc compiler. I have 4.6.3. I wanted to use the stable version that was released as version 4.2. Is there any way to compile that version with g++?

Comment: You could check out an older version of the project from svn, or you could update your compiler. I don't think it changes much in principle. Going forwards in time is normally better. Just for fun you could build gcc from source.

Comment: I tried to check out the read write version with this command mentioned in the m2s site: svn co svn+ssh://svnuser@multi2sim.org/multi2sim/trunk multi2sim  But this gives me permission denied error. I downloaded the read only version after that. When I configure this version it gives error that Makefile.in is not found. Any idea what is wrong?